# Volumes by slices and volume of cylinder

Tags: calculus, volume

So I am looking at this method of finding the volume of a solid by slices. The idea is to create slices/slabs which are cylinders/prisms and integrate them.

My problem is that in the book I'm using the volume of a cylinder/prims/slab is *assumed* to be:
$$V=Ah\tag{1}$$
so the volume is then:
$$\int_a^bA(x)dx$$

This method is then used to show that the volume of a cylinder is equation $(1)$. That is circular reasoning.

Am I missing something obvious or is the volume of a cylinder proved with more rigorous math to follow?

Comment: The problem as stated is circular.  However, the if the volume of a cylinder is proved using classical geometry, and the solid can be shown to be made from cylindrical cross sections of varying radii, A sphere for example, then this technique is useful to find the volumes of solids that are more interesting than a cylinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reasoning:

1. Define the volume of the prism to be $A(x)h$. This definition agrees with our intuition of volume.
2. We want the integral to compute volumes in a more abstract way. However, we want the integral to still give us our intuitive results like the volume of the prism is $A(x)h$, where $A(x)$ is the area of the base.
3. We compute the integral and huzzah! We get our original result!

In this way, what you are doing is more like verifying that the tools you've made do what you want them to do (compute volumes, and have these volumes agree in the selected ``intuitive" cases).

Of course, you could start by *defining* the area of a prism to be $\int_a^bA(x)\;\text{d}x$, and then as a *theorem* you get that the volume is $A(x)h$.

All depends on what you want to be theorems and definitions.

Comment: That makes sense, although it's strange to me that the area of a cylinder is defined rather then derived from something more basic. Btw, did you mean volume there at the end and not area?

Comment: Ah good catch! I edited it. Consider the two basic definitions:

Axiom 1. The length of a segment [a,b] is b-a. 
Axiom 2. The area of the set $A\times B$ is the area of $A$ times the area of $B$. 

With these two definitions, you can define the area of a rectangle, polygon, or even a circle. Then once you have these, you get the area of rectangles, prisms, and cylinders with another application of Axiom 2.

Comment: Ok, thx for the help.